# Javascript - create and destroy a toast message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a toast notification in javascript. When the user has done fine, a message box (the toast) should appear with a green color and the text "successfull" or whatever.

If not, the color is red and the text should be "failure". This div should be sliding from the top of the center of the screen, stay for 3 sec and after that, it should be removed from the DOM.

I got this one here, to create my div

```
CreateToast(isValid) { // Toast notification
        var toastDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var toastMessage;
        var foreColor;
        var backgroundColor;
        var borderColor;

        if (!isValid) {
            toastMessage = "Failure";
            foreColor = "";
            backgroundColor = "";
            borderColor = "";
        } else {
            toastMessage = "Success";
            foreColor = "";
            backgroundColor = "";
            borderColor = "";
        }

        toastDiv.innerHTML = toastMessage;
        document.body.appendChild(toastDiv);
    }
```

But what I don't know is, how to setup the rest of it. Where to place it, how it slides down from the top center etc.

I know, I can delete the div by using

```
toastDiv.remove(); // Delete the element from the DOM
```

but how to use it when it comes to "Destroy it after 3 sec" ?

Comment: For destroying, at the trigger event... you could use `setTimeout(....` function.

Comment: instead of adding style attributes - which just blows ur script, i would rather set classes and style them with css... e.g. all your toasts go into a wrapper (e.g. with the class .js-toasts) this one you can place anywhere. each toast gets a class (e.g. .js-toasts__item ([BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/))) + add a class for success + fail ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you tagged jQuery to your question, I assume you want to use some jQuery methods.

So this is the basic example: (I'm sure you will be able to style it as you wish)
To each created div, you have to assign a unique `id` in order to be able to make it `slideDown()` and to `.remove()` it.

So I added a `toastCounter` to create this `id`.

```js
var toastCounter=0;

function CreateToast(isValid) { // Toast notification
  
  var toastDiv = document.createElement("div");
  
  // Give it a unique id
  toastDiv.id = "toast_"+toastCounter;
  
  // Make it hidden (necessary to slideDown)
  toastDiv.style.display = "none";
  
  var toastMessage;
  var foreColor;
  var backgroundColor;
  var borderColor;

  if (!isValid) {
    toastMessage = "Failure";
    foreColor = "";
    backgroundColor = "";
    borderColor = "";
  } else {
    toastMessage = "Success";
    foreColor = "";
    backgroundColor = "";
    borderColor = "";
  }

  toastDiv.innerHTML = toastMessage;
  document.body.appendChild(toastDiv);
  
  // Increment toastCounter
  toastCounter++;
}



$("#test1").on("click",function(){
  CreateToast(true);
  var thisToast = toastCounter-1;
  
  // Make it slide down
  $(document).find("#toast_"+thisToast).slideDown(600);
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(document).find("#toast_"+thisToast).slideUp(600,function(){   // Slideup callback executes AFTER the slideup effect.
      $(this).remove();
    });
  },3000);  // 3sec.
});

$("#test2").on("click",function(){
  CreateToast(false);
  var thisToast = toastCounter-1;
  
  // Make it slide down
  $(document).find("#toast_"+thisToast).slideDown(600);
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(document).find("#toast_"+thisToast).slideUp(600,function(){   // Slideup callback executes AFTER the slideup effect.
      $(this).remove();
    });
  },3000);  // 3sec.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="test1">TRUE</button>
<button id="test2">FALSE</button>
```

Comment: so when you have this code here `$(document).find("#toast_" + thisToast).slideDown(600);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(document).find("#toast_" + thisToast).remove();
    }, 3000);` I am pretty shure, i can make the div slide up, before destroying it, no?

Comment: Sure! But then you have to `remove()` in the `.slideup()` callback. I'll edit the answer for more clarity than in comment here.

Answer (score 0):

I think based on your requirements you should take a look at the `toastr` library. I use it myself for several projects and it has a great API which allows a lot of customization.

See: https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

Answer (score 0):

You can show toast with JsFrame.js like below.

[image: toast message]

https://riversun.github.io/jsframe/examples/v150/toast_simple.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://riversun.github.io/jsframe/jsframe.js"></script>
<script>
    const jsFrame = new JSFrame();
    jsFrame.showToast({
        html: 'This is a simple toast', align: 'top', duration: 2000
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the library.
https://github.com/riversun/JSFrame.js